# Why Chrome renders all stuff slightly upscaled and blurry?

Tags: google-chrome, scale, blurry

some time ago (probably after recent update) I've noticed picture in my chrome changed a bit: everything rendered slightly upscaled and looks blurry. This issue affects everything: tabs, searchbar, bookmarks panel and of course all content in opened pages.

Here is some pic:

[image]

As you can see on screenshot, here Firefox window overlaps Chrome window, both of them shows the same page, and you can notice difference in sizes and blurriness. Do you have any ideas how to solve it?

Chrome version: 43.0.2357.130 on Kubuntu 14.04 (64-bit), it has default scale 100%. Also I found some info about [similar issue on windows](http://www.ghacks.net/2014/08/27/fix-latest-chrome-looking-zoomed-in-and-blurry/), but this didn't helps me, since there is no DirectWrite settings or something like that in my chrome.

Thanks.

Comment: No, it has default zoom 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some more deeper search gives me a link to chromium [issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=490964), which describes my situation. And there also I found a solution for me. In brief, you just need to run next console command:

```
xrandr --dpi 96x96
```

Hope, this helps somebody.